# Case SQLServer, como proceder?

Tags: sql-server

Estou tentando exibir uma coluna q está definida em 0 e 1 para que quando por 0 mostre 'Ok' e pra quando for 1 'NOK'.

Segue meu código que não está dando certo, mas pela consulta slq

```
String query1 = "Select DATA,HORA,RCPERFIL,BPCS,N_ETIQUETA,EMV_MIN,EMV_MAX,TMV,"
    + "ET5_MIN,ET5_MAX,TT5,"
    + "ETS2_MIN,ETS2_MAX,TTS2,"
    + "ET90_MIN, ET90_MAX,TT90,"
    + "EDENS_MIN,EDENS_MAX,TDENS,[EC-CHART],EBLOOMING = (CASE when EBLOOMING = '0 'then 'ok' else 'nok' END from
       QRY_MIX_LCSOMA where CONTAGEM_APROV = '0' and TIPOTESTE = 'Filtrado'
       ORDER BY DATA,HORA DESC";
```

Comment: ta retornando algum erro? ou exibe sempre ok?

Comment: pelo SQL exibe perfeitamente, mas pela IDE, fala q a sintaxe está errada no 'FROM'

Comment: Qual a `IDE`? Qual linguagem está utilizando pra executar a `query`? O problema pode estar ocorrendo devido a concatenação aí

Comment: Estou usando a IDE 'NetBeans' com a programação java e usando o método JDBC

Comment: tava olhando sua query e tá faltando um fechar parênteses depois do `END`

Comment: Sim, vc está certo.. mas quando fechei, deu outro erro, mas acho q sei.. acho q é pq declarei a coluna como int

Comment: era isso mesmo, desculpa pelo post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notei que o seu select faltou fechar os (), como esta usando um subselect é necessário usar a clausula select e o seu case esta verificando '0 ' e não '0',
baseando me em sql server o seu subselect ficaria assim:

```
(SELECT CASE when EBLOOMING = '0' then 'ok' else 'nok' AS NOMECOLUNA END from
       QRY_MIX_LCSOMA where CONTAGEM_APROV = '0' and TIPOTESTE = 'Filtrado')
```

OBS: Removi o order by por ser um subselect